# Are there any limits to the Magic School Bus's magic?

Tags: the-magic-school-bus

The Magic School Bus can do nearly everything - shrink, expand, transform into nearly any vehicle (even a tent), provide adequate food to its occupants, go back in time, go to space, bake a cake,and even enter someone's bloodstream.

So is there anything the Magic School Bus **can't** do?

Are there any limits to the Magic School Bus's magic?

(All TV shows, books (whether original, chapter or tie-in) and other sources are considered canon.)

Comment: A failure doesn't answer the question. I'm talking when the bus functions normally.

Comment: It can't kill anybody (so don't ask), it can't make anybody fall in love with anybody else and it can't bring people back from the dead (it's not a pretty picture).

Comment: @Valorum Source?

Comment: Ash, I'm pretty sure @Valorum was just making a joke. Those are the limitations of the wishes granted by Genie (from Disney's *Aladdin*).

Comment: It can't make a boulder that even _it_ can't lift.

Comment: How is this too broad? Based on other questions on this site this should be acceptable.

Comment: Edited to "Are there any limits to the Magic School Bus's magic?"

Comment: @TheAsh Still too broad, you will have to narrow it down to a specific problem.

Comment: Should be reopened as per meta: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11540

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### It can't make its own fuel.

Magic School Bus inside a Hurricane:
[image]